# Laravel: How to display Has Many Through Many to Many based on the number of nested relationships

Tags: laravel, collections, many-to-many, has-many-through

I am facing a small difficulty in finding the best way to get nested relationships through two many-to-many many relationships.

I have 3 models: Article, Keyword and Subject with the following relationships:

Article <-> Keyword (many to many);

Article <-> Subject (many to many).

What I am trying to do is getting one subject's keywords based on all the subject's articles so I can display them as a bubble with scalable size.

The code so far:

```
$subject = Subject::with('articles.keywords')->find($id);
    $keywordsArray = $subject->articles->pluck('keywords');
    $keywords = (new Collection($keywordsArray))->collapse()->groupBy('id');

return $keywords; // returns the collection with all the duplicate keywords
return $keywords->unique('id') // returns unique keywords.
```

I know to return the count mapping from the collection like this:

```
$keywordsCount = (new Collection($keywordsArray))->collapse()->groupBy('id')->map(function($item, $key){
        return $item->count();
    });
    return $keywordsCount; // returns ex: {"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"6":1}
```

Everything works, the only question that remains is: how do I merge the unique keywords with $keywordsCount, or, what is the best way to utilize these 2 so I can resize the keyword's bubble based on that count.

Many thanks in advance and godspeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how often you'll need to retrieve that merged information, but for that collection you've retrieved now you can always simply assign the count as a temporary attribute to every current `keyword` instance in the collection. 
Alternatively, you can also just pack both up in an array, for which matter I'd simply do something like using the `zip()` collection method:

```
return $keywords->unique('id')->zip($keywordsCount);
```

which will create a collection of coupled arrays like `[['keyword1', 1], ['keyword2', 3], ...]` thus merging the information as you wished.